# In Ruby, how to make a new instance of a model with all the same attribute values (excepting id) of an existing instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app and I have a model called Activity.  I want to be able to make a new instance of Activity and have it be an exact copy of an existing instance of Activity, except that it has a different ID.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dup` will make a "shallow copy", then save the new activity.

```
@new_activity = @old_activity.dup
@new_activity.save
```